# "Unwrapped" XML data is valid against XSD of "Wrapper"

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

A set of XSD can defines a complex tree-like structure.

For example, to represent this sample model:

```
LogicFileSample
 +--- Bulk A
         +---- Detail A1
         +---- Detail A2
 +--- Bulk B
         +---- Detail B1
         +---- Detail B2
         ...
 +--- ...
```

`LogicFileSample` and `Bulk` have some extra attributes, `Detail` is only a String.

You can implement 2 XSD schema:

**1. LogicFileSample.xsd**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:bulk="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:BulkSample"  
    xmlns:logFs="urn:LogicFileSample:xsd:$LogicFileSample.xsd"
    targetNamespace="urn:LogicFileSample:xsd:$LogicFileSample.xsd"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <!-- IMPORT -->
    <xs:import namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:BulkSample" schemaLocation="BulkSample.xsd"/>

    <xs:element name="LogicFileSampleRoot">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="SuperField01" type="logFs:Max5Text" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="SuperField02" type="logFs:Max5Text" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <!-- Bulks Container -->
                <xs:element name="BulksContainer" type="bulk:BulkSegmentType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:simpleType name="Max5Text">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="[0-9A-Z]{5,5}"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

**2. BulkSample.xsd**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<xs:schema
    xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:BulkSample"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    targetNamespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:BulkSample"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="Document" type="DocumentType"/>
    <xs:complexType name="DocumentType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="BulksContainer" type="BulkSegmentType"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="BulkSegmentType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="BulkHeader"    type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="DetailElement" type="xs:string" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Now, if you create an XML file with `n` bulks wrapped in a `LogicFileSample` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<logFs:LogicFileSampleRoot 
    xmlns:logFs="urn:LogicFileSample:xsd:$LogicFileSample.xsd" 
    xmlns:bulk="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:BulkSample"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <!-- LogicFileSample info fields -->
  <logFs:SuperField01>ABCDE</logFs:SuperField01>
  <logFs:SuperField02>12345</logFs:SuperField02>
  <!-- 3 BulksContainer -->
  <logFs:BulksContainer>
    <bulk:BulkHeader>BulkHeader_A</bulk:BulkHeader>
    <bulk:DetailElement>DetailElement_A1</bulk:DetailElement>
    <bulk:DetailElement>DetailElement_A2</bulk:DetailElement>
  </logFs:BulksContainer>
    <logFs:BulksContainer>
    <bulk:BulkHeader>BulkHeader_B</bulk:BulkHeader>
    <bulk:DetailElement>DetailElement_B1</bulk:DetailElement>
    <bulk:DetailElement>DetailElement_B2</bulk:DetailElement>
    <bulk:DetailElement>DetailElement_B3</bulk:DetailElement>
  </logFs:BulksContainer>
    <logFs:BulksContainer>
    <bulk:BulkHeader>BulkHeader_C</bulk:BulkHeader>
    <bulk:DetailElement>DetailElement_C1</bulk:DetailElement>
  </logFs:BulksContainer>
</logFs:LogicFileSampleRoot>
```

...you can validate against "LogicFileSample.xsd" and it works (nice).

Then, you can create a lonely "bulk" XML file, unwrapped. Like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blk:Document 
    xmlns:blk="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:BulkSample"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <blk:BulksContainer>
    <blk:BulkHeader>BulkHeader_X</blk:BulkHeader>
    <blk:DetailElement>DetailElement_X1</blk:DetailElement>
    <blk:DetailElement>DetailElement_X2</blk:DetailElement>
  </blk:BulksContainer>
</blk:Document>
```

and if you validate against "BulkSample.xsd" the result is OK.

**B U T . . .**

What happens if you grab the "unwrapped" XML file and you try to validate against "LogicFileSample.xsd"?

Well... it's VALID against "LogicFileSample.xsd"!

Why? First of all, root element is `Document` (instead of `LogicFileSampleRoot`) and the mandatory <del>attributes</del> elements  `SuperField`... are not present!

Kindly, somebody can explain the reason why?

Comment: Ps. **javax.xml.validation.Validator** has been used to validate against XSD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why? First of all, root element is "Document" (instead of
>   "LogicFileSampleRoot")

Because any element globally defined in the XSD is allowed to be used as a root element in the XML document.  When you import another XSD into the base XSD, the globally defined elements there are then too allowed to be used as root elements.

> and the mandatory attributes "SuperField..." are not present!

Mandatory components (*elements*, in this case, actually, but attributes too) are only mandatory for the associated parent element.  So, `SuperField` is only required for `LogicFileSampleRoot`, not for the document in general regardless of the parent element.

Comment: Your answer is clear: you confirmed my suspicion. Thank you so much!

Comment: _"Because any element globally defined in the XSD is allowed to be used as a root element in the XML document"_  Why XSD allow definition of multiple root element, if XML documents must contain one root element at a time? @kjhughes

Comment: It's that ***any one*** of the globally defined elements ***might*** be ***the*** root element, not that multiple root elements might exist concurrently.

Comment: Thank you. Probably I asked in a wrong way. I would like to know the reason why XSD schemas give the ability to choice between more than one root. But I think that this is another question...